# Change Storyboard View using Seague

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, segue, viewcontroller

I have the following code that checks for connection to my server, and depending on that I want it to change views if no connection is found.

```
NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if (connect == NULL) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"network_failure" sender:self];
} else {
    // My other code here
}
```

My problem is that it will not change views. I have added a storyboard segue between the two views with the identifier of `network_failure`. I do not have a navigation controller or anything like that, is that a problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See if you are missing this method: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a problem.

First of all, in `ObjectiveC` exists `nil` that is an **object oriented NULL**. You must be use that. So:

```
if(connect == nil)
```

or better:

```
if(!connect)
```

So due the fact that `nil` is not the same of `NULL`, **probably your code does't enter in the if scope**.

**you would have been able to discover this with a simply breakpoint.**

ANYWAY:

Be sure to **set the trigger segue (line) from the 2 view controller**, and with the **name `network_failure`** (that is not the best name. Should be instead something like `View1ToView2`) as well as, the modality `modal` and not `push` because you haven't a `NavigationController`.

Comment: what do you mean by setting the trigger segue in the second view controller?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use nil and not NULL like Matteo Gobbi said . and then if you don't have a navigation controller you should call the 2nd viewController modaly. First you create a class for the second VC then import it to the firstVC.m and then you need to set the same class to the second VC in the storyboard  . After that you make the connection, choose modal and give it a nice segue identifier. Then you can implement the following to see the second VC

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"(yourSegueIdentifier)"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"(yourSegueIdentifier)" sender:self];
}
```

Give it a try (untested code).